# Show Android SnackBar above keyboard?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

Is it possible to show the [Android Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) above the keyboard (as in Y coordinate, not layering)? The Snackbar currently gets hidden if the keyboard is shown, which is an undesirable behavior.

Comment: Because we couldn't figure this out, we just hide the keyboard whenever we display a snackbar now (which we use for errors)

Comment: If you have a keyboard, you'll usually get the best experience using a plain old Toast. This will be shown over the keyboard, and you don't need to hide the keyboard (which might confuse the user)

Answer (score 100):

Set

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for the activity containing your snackbar

Comment: How do you put that in an activity?

Comment: It goes in the AndroidManifest.xml file as an attribute of the Activity in question.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it also adjusts the entire screen, which isn't something that we want. We only want the snackbar to be adjusted, not the entire screen.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but I have found that using a DrawerLayuot results in snackbar not showing above the keyboard. If I remove DrawerLayout from the activity, it shows as it should.

Comment: @fobbymaster, why did you mark this as the answer if as you say "isn't something that we want"?

Answer (score 18):

If you nest your layout in a ScrollView, the snackbar will appear on top of the keyboard.  This is because the view will resize to take up only the available space above the keyboard.  And, of course, your View will also be scroll-able if necessary at any time, while the keyboard is shown or not.

Comment: Using this with android:fillViewport="true" to make sure ScrollView fill the entire screen should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 9):

You can hide the keyboard when the `Snackbar` is shown.

```java
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: in case your snackbar is a response to a typing to a textedit this is very unfriendly to user as it could end up with clicking on anything else and unpleasant to see (flickering). better is to nest with scrollviewer

Answer (score 5):

**Jetpack Compose:**

Based on `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets.Companion).ime())

1. Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Call `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` in your Activity `onCreate` method
3. Finally, add `WindowInsets.ime.asPaddingValues()` to your Snackbar's `modifier` like this:

```kotlin
    Snackbar(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(vertical = 32.dp, horizontal = 16.dp)
            .padding(WindowInsets.ime.asPaddingValues()),
    ...
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following works:

1. Ensure the activity/fragment from which you are calling the `Snackbar` contains a `ScrolView`.
2. Ensure you set the snackbar view to `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`:

`Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "hello world").show();`

3. OR, if you want to be able to swipe away the `Snackbar`, ensure the `ScrolView` is nested within a `CoordinatorLayout`.

`Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.my_coordinator_layout), "hello world").show();`

Comment: I loved the 2nd solution. Short, clear and no hacks.

Answer (score 2):

**I have solved the issue like this:**

**Create a class:**

```
public class ShowSnackBar {
    public static void show(Context context, String message, View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**You can access this class from any activity in the application**

**Usage:**

```
ShowSnackBar.show(LoginOtpActivity.this,"Please enter Email ID /Mobile",linear_container);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem myself and was able to solve it quite easily.

Previously, I had set  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

The solution is to set it to false, or just delete that line. 
Now, you don't need to hide the keyboard to get your desired result.

Here is my layout file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_gap"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/input_a_number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoPersonalizedLearning"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusedByDefault="true"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            tools:targetApi="o" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="180dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_gap"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/jade"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/jade_fab"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Jetpack Compose Solution

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` set the `windowSoftInputMode` inside your `<activity .. >`:

```xml
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Then, add

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    snackbarHost = { 
        SnackbarHost(
            hostState = snackBarHostState, 
            modifier = Modifier.imePadding()
        )
    }
}
```

You may also need to set the following on `WindowCompat`. I placed it in my `theme.kt`.

```kotlin
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(currentWindow, false)
```

Lastly, the `OutlinedTextField()` and the `snackBarHostState`/`snackbar` should show on top of the soft or on-screen keyboard. You may need `modifier.imePadding()` for the `OutlinedTextField()` as well.

Comment: It looks like `Modifier.imePadding()` isn't even necessary, at which point, this is the same as the answer from giorgos.nl which has the most votes.

Answer (score -1):

This is my code for snackbar and its working similarly+ as you need
 relativeLayout is the parent main layout id i have passed.

```
        snackbar=snackbar.make(relativeLayout,"Image is Saved to "+Savedfile.getPath().toString(),Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        snackbar.dismiss();
                        snackbar=null;

                        System.gc();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

this is my code , there is no need to set view from method , you can get it from DecoreView :

```
public static void longSnack(final String text) {
    hideKeyboard();
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(context.getWindow().getDecorView(), text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    snackbar.show();
}

public static void shortSnack(final String text) {
    hideKeyboard();
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(context.getWindow().getDecorView(), text, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    snackbar.show();
}

private static void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager != null) {
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context on why your code is a valid answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

**Add snack bar in this way, place a Container @ content argument, with padding from bottom of Keyboard size.**

```
SnackBar snackBar = 
        SnackBar( 
                 content: Container(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.only( bottom: 
                                 MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                         child: Text('Please add your quote !!!')),
                         duration: Duration(milliseconds:  800),
                              );
          // Add this given line in function body where to show snack bar
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context.showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).