# Android - Snackbar position and overlay the soft keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, position, android-softkeyboard, snackbar

My applications have a Toast. But if the soft keyboard is displayed the Toast sort of merged with the soft keyboard and is hard to distinguish. So I looked up how to set a custom view to a Toast. But the View property (SetView and GetView methods) is deprecated.
Instead I was told to use a Snackbar.
I have managed to create a Snackbar with a custom view. I have these problems:

1. **The Snackbar's position is in the lower left corner of my app.**
   I would like to display the Snackbar as a Toast is displayed:

   - At the bottom and in the middle of the screen.
   - Some distance between the Snackbar's bottom and the screen's bottom.
2. **The Snackbar is displayed behind the soft keyboard**.
   I would like to display the Snackbar above the soft keyboard.
   I can hide the soft keyboard to show the Snackbar. But I would prefer not to hide it.

I have googled a lot on these two problems, but have not found any solutions.

**For problem #1 I have tried**

- [How can you adjust Android SnackBar to a specific position on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492351/how-can-you-adjust-android-snackbar-to-a-specific-position-on-screen)

  - I was not able to get the `CoordinatorLayout` to compile.
  - Setting the margin on a Layout didn't work.

**For problem #2 I have tried**

- [Show Android SnackBar above keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138433/show-android-snackbar-above-keyboard) but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

**res/layout/snackbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView style="@style/SomeStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tvSnackbarText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Snackbar" />
```

**Fragment**

```
private fun showSnackbarMessage(message: String) {
    val view: View = LayoutInflater
        .from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.snackbar, null)

    val tvSnackbarText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvSnackbarText)
    tvSnackbarText.text = message
    tvSnackbarText.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(requireView(), "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    snackbar.view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner_box_grey_stroke);

    val params = snackbar.view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
    params.height = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    params.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    snackbar.view.layoutParams = params

    val layout = snackbar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout
    layout.addView(view)

    snackbar.show()
}
```